# Looking for the correct way in Linux to write encrypted text from C++ application to encrypted gpg file

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, encryption, gnupg

I have Linux C++ application ported from Solaris OS and the app needs to write some text data via gpg (or gpg2) into encrypted file. So the text data should be written directly to gpg (encrypted file).
I create pipes:

```
if(pipe(pipes) == -1)
  throw Exception("Error creating pipes");

switch(fork())
{
  case -1:
    throw Exception("fork() failure");
  case 0: // child process
    close(pipes[PIPE_PARENT]);
    close(READ);
    close(ERR);
    if(dup(pipes[PIPE_CHILD]) != READ)
      throw Exception("dup() failure, READ descriptor unavailable");

    execlp("gpg", "gpg", "--no-tty", "-r", "username", "-e", "-o", "home/username/out.pgp", NULL);
    break;
}
```

...
Then I use write():

```
intWCount = write(intTextFD, strData.str().c_str(), strData.str().size());
```

Then I see errno == 9, intWCount = -1.
From STDOUT I get:

"gpg: WARNING: standard error reopened"

and the text data is not written to the file.
I use Ubuntu 16.04, gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.20, gcc 5.4.0.

The main question is - how to write my text data into encrypted gpg file securely?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.gnupg.org/APIs states this:

> A number of elder applications call GnuPG executables in a subprocess and interact with them via command line arguments and file-descriptors. This is less perferable to GPGME, because the command line arguments and text outputs are not an (official) API to GnuPG. While there is an effort made to keep them stable, using the official GPGME API can manage this more precisely and thus you end up with a more robust solution.

The correct way is using gpgme as an api, it has c++ bindings.

If you are absolutely sure you want to do that on your own you might want to consider popen()ening the binary without "--no-tty" and writing to the resulting file pointer. This is sub optimal, though, as GnuPG is wont to ask questions and you need to be ready to have your program answer them.

Using the API is much preferable.

Comment: Thank you, I thought the suggested way. I used -r [username] switch and the tests in the terminal had no warnings or errors. At the same time I tried to remove "--no-tty" in gpg options but with the same result - I got the warning in debug/Output and gpg was unusable (errno 9).

Comment: Is ERR maybe the same FD as STDERR? Have you tried doing the same thing without closing() ERR? To me it looks like GnuPG complains about not having STERR and having to reopen it.

I simply did
int main(void)
{
        FILE *fp = popen("gpg2 -r 1346E6A5 -e -o /tmp/out.pgp", "w");
        write("foo", fp, 4);
        return(0);
}

Comment: I tried both ways. And when I tried to simulate the action with command the gpg (gpg -e -r username -o filename) did not write the text from the keyboard to the file. gpg made the file, it made the header only.